# Symfony2 Forms - Submit cloned fields in javascript

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have entity named Document and it has fields named 'date', 'number', etc.

On page, user can add new document from FORM, it's easy, but(!) I need to allow user to clone fields and add few document at once, user can push 'add' (it's cloning fields in form) button many times, and I want to add all these entities in controller.

This is my FormType class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option) {
    $builder->add('date', 'text', array(
        'required'  =>  false,
        'attr'  =>  array(
            'class' =>  'datepicker no-right-margin'
        )
    ));
    $builder->add('number', 'text', array(
        'required'  =>  false
    ));
    ...
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'documenttype';
}
```

I tried to hardcode input's name from:

> documenttype[date]

to

> documenttype[date][0]
>   documenttype[date][1]
>   ...etc

...but it doesn't work. It gave me

```
    object(Ewidencja\CoreBundle\Entity\Document)#406 (8) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["date":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-01"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-08-02"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [*How to Embed a Collection of Forms*](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) cookbook entry. Particularty you are interested in the [`allow_add`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) option.